# Developing for Android on the phone itself

Tags: java, android, c

I read  about AIDE and it's ability to develop and compile Java directly on Android but what about C support? I read that the PC Android NDK adds full C support only if you wrap it in a dll but a newer version would allow apps to be developed directly in C without any wrapper.
Is there anything like that for Android as well? I know of c4droid and it's gcc plugin but I assume that is for developing for x86 and not ARM.

Comment: Why would you want to write code on a phone?  That sounds like a horrible experience!

Comment: Simply out of love of programming and a lack of PC for the next few months...

Comment: There are some packages now which claim to give you the ability to build android apps on the phone (or more realistically perhaps, tablet).  Another option might be remote connection to a cloud machine running a normal linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could install linux (Ubuntu, in this case) on your phone and put your development environment in there, I guess.

Check https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.ubuntuinstall

Answer (score 1):

With Android Native Development Kit (NDK) you can implement *parts* of your application using C.  http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html. If you write native code, your applications are still packaged into an .apk file and they still run inside of a virtual machine on the device. The fundamental Android application model does not change.

Comment: Native code does not actually run inside the DVM, though it normally runs in a process which has a DVM for interacting with the android platform.  Additionally, as an unofficial feature the ndk will build commandline executables which can currently be launched from a terminal emulator (or adb) shell, though those aren't really "apps" and have no ordinary user interface.  Presumably it would not be impossible to port the necessary parts of the ndk to run on android atop bionic libc, though it might be easier to port it to run in a more traditional linux-like environment in a chroot.

Comment: I agree with this answer, there's not a separate environment (based on C/C++) to write apps, and there's no fundamental whole app support for C/C++ based systems.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NDK with JNI (Java Native Interface)
the following example is simple and could help you to understand quickly the NDK and JNI:

[Using NDK to Call C code from Android Apps](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html)

The following document contains more examples and details concerning the use of NDK and JNI

[JNI Examples for Android](http://android.wooyd.org/JNIExample/files/JNIExample.pdf)

Your C code will be build as dynamic linux library (.so) and will be loaded when your application start. The use of JNI will allow your JAVA code to use the C functions from the library. The use of such solution (calling C function from JAVA) is very useful especially if you have complicated and long duration algorithms. executing such algoritms in C take much less time comparing to Java.

Comment: My question was fundamentally different. I asked whether I could write and compile C on Android FOR Android much like the AIDE app.

Comment: are you looking to develop the whole application with c? even for the user interface ? if that's true my answer will not help you.

Comment: I found this url I do not know if it helps you https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=GDE.Main&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEwOSwiR0RFLk1haW4iXQ..